# Specify order of tables to copy using the Copy Data tool in Azure Data Factory to respect foreign keys

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

The [Copy Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-copy-data-tool) tool lets me select the tables I want to copy from the source to the destination, but the tables are copied in **alphabetical** order. Since I have foreign keys defined, this cannot work. I would like to manually change the order.

Comment: I haven't used this tool itself but it looks like it creates pipeline(s) for you.  Can you edit those pipelines to change or enforce the order?  I have created pipelines where I feed it an array of names and a For Each with a copy inside it - haven't tested the sequencing but it seems like it does it in the order of the array.

Comment: @ScottMildenberger Yes it does create a pipeline. There's a "cw_items" parameter that contains a minimized 300-line JSON in which I had my 4 tables and all the mappings int it, I was able to change the order there but it was quite painful! Not a scalable solution obviously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple pipeline that copies data from one database to another - it has a ForEach with 2 activities inside it.  It copies each table and then runs a stored procedure after each table.  The column names in the tables are the same.  It has a variable called tableMapping that is a json array that defines the 'from' and 'to' table names as they can be different.  The ForEach has this setting "batchCount": 1, so that it runs one at a time.  In my testing just now it processes the tables in the sequence in the variable tableMapping.  If you don't specify the batchCount = 1 then it will run them in parallel.

```
{
    "name": "TowWorks to Azure SQL DB",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@variables('tableMapping')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "batchCount": 1,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Copy from BI to Azure",
                            "type": "Copy",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "source": {
                                    "type": "SqlServerSource",
                                    "queryTimeout": "02:00:00"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "type": "AzureSqlSink",
                                    "preCopyScript": {
                                        "value": "@{concat('truncate table raw.', item().to)}",
                                        "type": "Expression"
                                    },
                                    "disableMetricsCollection": false
                                },
                                "enableStaging": false
                            },
                            "inputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "BI_TW_Raw_NoTable",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "tableName": {
                                            "value": "@item().from",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "outputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "TW_Azure_DB_noTable",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "schema": "raw",
                                        "table": {
                                            "value": "@item().to",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Stored Procedure1",
                            "type": "SqlServerStoredProcedure",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Copy from BI to Azure",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "storedProcedureName": {
                                    "value": "@concat('raw.Update', item().to)",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            },
                            "linkedServiceName": {
                                "referenceName": "TowWorksAzureSqlDB",
                                "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "tableMapping": {
                "type": "Array",
                "defaultValue": [
                    {
                        "from": "WORK_TASKS",
                        "to": "WorkTask"
                    },
                    {
                        "from": "Invoice",
                        "to": "Invoice"
                    },
                    {
                        "from": "ASSET",
                        "to": "Asset"
                    },
                    {
                        "from": "InvoiceDistribution",
                        "to": "InvoiceDistribution"
                    },
                    {
                        "from": "InvoiceEvent",
                        "to": "InvoiceEvent"
                    },
                    {
                        "from": "InvoiceTransaction",
                        "to": "InvoiceTransaction"
                    },
                    {
                        "from": "LOGISTICS_ORDERS",
                        "to": "LogisticOrder"
                    },
                    {
                        "from": "LOGISTICS_ORDERS_LINE_ITEMS",
                        "to": "LogisticOrderLineItem"
                    },
                    {
                        "from": "WORK_ORDERS",
                        "to": "WorkOrder"
                    },
                    {
                        "from": "WORK_ORDERS_STATUSES",
                        "to": "WorkOrderStatus"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "from": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "to": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "folder": {
            "name": "TowWorks"
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately,as i know,[ADF copy activity SQL DB connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database#dataset-properties) only could transfer tables in the default order.It can't scan your constraint policy and execute in the optimal order.

So,i'm afraid that you have to figure out how your constraint policy set up and make the right order manually.After getting the table name sorting list,create the copy activity one by one for every table.

Surely,don't worry about this part.Every element could be created by [ADF SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-python) or [Powershell script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-powershell).All you need to do is looping the list and pass it into snippet of code or script.Only the table name need to be changed per activity.